# Problems with calling function from one js file to another

Tags: javascript

In the file data.js i have:

```
(function () {

   data() 

   function runThisWhenDataIsFinished() {

        console.log("Works!"); 

   }


})();
```

In the file app.js i have

```
function data() {

    console.log("Im in the data function");

    runThisWhenDataIsFinished();

}
```

When i call on data() i  get the message "Im in the data function", when i try to call on the runThisWhenDataIsFinished() method i get error: runThisWhenDataIsFinished() method is not defined.

So how can i access runThisWhenDataIsFinished method in data.js from app.js?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments :

- first, you define "runThisWhenDataIsFinished" *after* calling the "data()" function ; so there is no way the function is defined
- event if you call "data()" after defining the function, it will not work, because, as explaied otherwise, it will only be defined in the scope of the anonymous function.

There is something that would work, but do *not* do that :

```
function data() {

  console.log("Im in the data function");

  // The 'globalRunThisWhenDataIsFinished' function is no defined in this scope, 
  // so it will only be called if it exists as a *global* variable
  globalRunThisWhenDataIsFinished();

}

(function () {

   // When calling the anonymous function like you do, 
   // 'this' is the Window object, so you can add "global" variables
   // like this. However you probably DO NOT WANT TO DO THAT
   this.globalRunThisWhenDataIsFinished = function() {

      console.log("Works!"); 

   }

   data();

})();
```

As pointed out, I suggest you look at the Module pattern to understand what you really want to do.

Comment: I understand never use global var, if you read my other questions you will get the context what im doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026352/how-to-populate-list-in-windows8-with-javascript i cant get it to work, it like a dead end =)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because `runThisWhenDataIsFinished` is lexically scoped (to it's parent function). If you want to be able to access it outside of that scope you will have to use some sort of global namespace.

See http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much that these are in different files, but that `runThisWhenDataIsFinished()` is in an anonymous function. If you move this outside of the function, as long as `data.js` has been loaded before making a `data()` call it will run it correctly.

Comment: Technically, runThisWhenDataIsFinished is not an anonymous function, it is scoped to the function that it is defined in.  In order to be an anonymous function, it can't be named.  :)  Not trying to be an asshat, just trying to avoid confusion for the op.

Comment: @ilanberci I didn't say `runThisWhenDataIsFinished()` is an anonymous function. I said its in an anonymous function. It is scoped to an anonymous function.