# How to populate list in windows8 with javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8

Im trying to build an windows8 app, i use the SplitApp as basic. Just trying to add data from AJAX but it fails.

In the file data.js i have:

```
(function () {

    var list = new WinJS.Binding.List();

    $.each(data(), function (key, item) {
        list.push(item);
    }); 

}
})();
```

In the file app.js i have **(This works and populates the list in the app)**

```
function data() {

   var testGroupMeeting = [];
   var testMeeting = [];

   testGroupMeeting.push(new Group({ id: "1", title: "Group1" }));

   testMeeting.push(new Meeting({ group: testGroupMeeting[0], title: "Item Title: 1"       }));

   return testMeeting;


}
```

But when i want to use AJAX to get data and return testMeeting when it is populated it crashes.

In the file app.js i have **(Doesnt work) but i need to get this to work**

```
function data() {

   var testGroupMeeting = [];
   var testMeeting = [];

$.ajax({
    url: "/json/json.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'text/json',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {

           //Data here is correct and mapped to the arrays, its the same as in the abow example, i have the same data in the arrays as in the above example



        }
        return testMeeting;
    }

});


}
```

But the problem seems to be that AJAX is not supposed to be returning anything. And i cant do a callback to data.js because that function is anonymous as you can see.

How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

This can not work this way, because the $.ajax function is asynchronous : it does the ajax call, and then, later, calls the "success" function with the appropriate data.

You'll have rewrite the $.each(data() ... so that instead of calling data() and expecting it to return testMeeting , you call data and expect it to call a callback with the testMetting object.

Something like :

```
(function () {

    var list = new WinJS.Binding.List();

    getData(function (theMetting) {


        $.each(theMeeting, function (key, item) {
          list.push(item);
        }); 

 }
})();


// callback is a function that will be called with 
// something that is built from the server, after the ajax
// request is done
function getData(callback) {


 $.ajax({
    // ... everything you did ... 
    success: function (data) {

       // ... use the data to build the meeting object
       // and pass it to the callback
       callback(meeting)


    }
    return testMeeting;
}

});

}
```

There is a fundamental difference between synchronous code (that returns functions) and asynchonous calls (that does some work, and later calls callback with the result). $.ajax is the typicall asynchronous function.

You *could* in theory pass the "async" flag to ajax, so that the $.ajax function does not return before the Ajax call is done, but you probably do not want to do that since it would block you UI.

Hoping this helps.

Comment: The problem is that the     getData(function (theMetting) {


        $.each(theMeeting, function (key, item) {
          list.push(item);
        }); 

 } is in anonymous function by default from microsoft, and i cant access it from my app.js as you suggested, or?

Comment: No, the getData is just the function that you could write instead of the "data" function. I assumed that all code was yours - If you can not change the function from data.js, and the only way you can modify the application is by defining the "data" function, then you will have to make a synchronous (*not* asynchronous) call to your server - you can do it by passing a flag to the $.ajax function. Then, the $.ajax function will wait until the "success" callback has been done...

Comment: Now, to be clear, I don't really understand what you mean by "in a anomymous function by default from ms". All I can tell you is that the $.each(data(), .... ) version will only work if data() *returns* an Array, and you will not be able to write a function that *returns* data from an asynchronous call to the server. Either you make it a synchronous call, or you rewrite the loop to adapt it. Hoping this helps.